# Is there any way to push to the front of a channel in golang?

Tags: go, concurrency

In golang channels, the element pushed last is consumed last. But is there a way to push element to the "front" of the channel so that the element get a chance to get consumed out of turn?  Assume elements 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 are added to the channel and element 4 failed to process (1,2,3 are processed successfully). In this case I want to push the element 4 again to the channel in such a way that it may get a chance to get processed before elements 5,6,7,8 and subsequent elements added (if they are not already pulled from the channel for processing). This can be easily achieved using blocking queues. But I don't want to use them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166789). It's always best to describe the goal you're trying to accomplish, instead of the solution you think that might fit.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker the problem I had lots of messages are pushed to a channel and from the channel some consumer gets the message and process them. Sometimes the processing fails (because the target service times out or some other issues). If the processing fails, then they need to be retried and retry of failed messages should ideally happen before the newly arrived messages. Also, the processing of the messages and getting failed or success response for them happen asynchronously.

Comment: @NipunTalukdar: Have you considered using some message queueing software or library? If message delivery guarantees is important there are solutions that will likely be a lot more robust than rolling it yourself (e.g. what about persistence if the process dies?). If you don't need that and just want something simple and lightweight, how about just having a retry loop in the handler rather than enqueueing the message again?

Comment: @JosefGrahn yes. We are using Kafka. Scenario is like this. Some PHP web components push events to a local event collector (which is golang component) which evaluates the events and if fine pushes it to Kafka. I am using sarama kafka library from Shopify and I am using the async producer. The response from Kafka comes asynchronously. If it gets a failed response from Kafka, that event needs to be retried (push again to Kafka) and ideally that should be retried before the newer events. Eventcollector pushes the events to a channel, nd from the channel a goroutine peek and send to async producer

Comment: It really feels like you are going at the problem from the wrong angle... Why don't you just have a basic retry loop in a goroutine? The goroutine can wait 
(synchronously) for the response from Kafka. Spawn one per message push or keep a pool of workers. But that channel and goroutine is still a week link in your message delivery unless you also push failures downstream and let them handle it (i.e. don't ack the clients until you have pushed it onto the Kafka queue).

Answer (score 4):

> But is there a way to push element to the "front" of the channel

No there is not.

Answer (score 2):

No, a channel is strictly FIFO. You'll have to play with multiple channels if you want priority, or use some other data structure, like a heap: https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/.